# VBA If-statement with AND Operator

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am using the following code which works perfectly:

```
If ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 And ComboBox4.ListIndex = 3 Then
ID1 = "GS-T10-"
Elseif ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 And ComboBox4.ListIndex = 4 Then
ID1 = "PB-"
Elseif ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 And ComboBox4.ListIndex = 5 Then
ID1 = "PE-"
```

As you can see It is if statement with AND operator evaluating 2 conditions.
However notice that my first condition is always the same (ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0), and only the second condition is changing. Is there a way to just write the first condition (which is not changing) once at the beginning of the IF Statement and hence only write the second condition after each Elseif??

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, you have one if testing (ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0) and 3 nested if that evaluate ComboBox4.ListIndex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should "take out" the repeating condition to outer `If` statement, like this:

```
If ComboBox3.ListIndex = 0 Then
    If ComboBox4.ListIndex = 3 Then
        ID1 = "GS-T10-"
    Elseif ComboBox4.ListIndex = 4 Then
        ID1 = "PB-"
    Elseif ComboBox4.ListIndex = 5 Then
        ID1 = "PE-" 
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @OP also note the proper *indentation* here, which is crucial for readability of such nested structures.

Comment: Yep thankkss! That was dumb from me, should have been clear :p

Comment: @Omar You should accept the answer if it helped you.